# JSON to HTML table using 'datatable' plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-plugins, datatables

I'm trying to generate a HTML data table from the result of a SQL query execution. The resulting data is in JSON format. I'm using the plugin "Datatables" to achieve this. I'm following this [example](http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html)

I don't get an error but the data table is empty. I'm obviously doing something wrong or missing something.

Here's the code excerpt. Could I please get some guidance on to the right path please.

```
function jsDataPlot(chartProps) {
    // Get the array from the element:
    var graphPropsStore = chartProps;

    // Loop through the array with the jQuery each function:
    $.each(graphPropsStore, function (k, graphPropsStoreProperty) {

        // The makeCall function returns a ajaxObject so the object gets put in var promise
        var dbResAjx = getResultFromSql(k);

        // Now fill the success function in this ajaxObject (could also use .error() or .done() )
        dbResAjx.success(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            // When success, call the function and use the values out of the array above
            $('#divId').DataTable(response);
        });

        dbResAjx.error(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
}


    function getResultFromSql(paramId) {
// bla bla code
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'runMySqlQuery.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {// some POST params}
        });
    }
```

JSON Result

```
[{"DATE":"2015-12-15","TYPE":"AAA","NAME":"asdasd"},{"DATE":"2015-12-15","TYPE":"BBB","NAME":"dsfsdfsdfsdf"},{"DATE":"2015-12-15","TYPE":"AAA","NAME":"reterter"},{"DATE":"2015-12-15","TYPE":"CCC","NAME":"ertertertert"}]
```

Comment: You can't call the `DataTable()` function directly with your data. See [here](http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) for more information on how to set up datatables with AJAX.

Comment: `#divId` is your id of table?, if it is true you have to pass the parameter data `$('#divId').DataTable({data : response});`.

Comment: Thankyou Cmedina. It still doesn't work. I get an index error that points me to look at `http://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4`

Comment: @usert4jju7 you can show the content of your `response`

Comment: Thank you CMedina. I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, in your JSON yu have this. DATE - TYPE - NAME

```
 [
    {"DATE":"2015-12-15","TYPE":"AAA","NAME":"asdasd"},
    {"DATE":"2015-12-15","TYPE":"BBB","NAME":"dsfsdfsdfsdf"},
    {"DATE":"2015-12-15","TYPE":"AAA","NAME":"reterter"},
    {"DATE":"2015-12-15","TYPE":"CCC","NAME":"ertertertert"}
 ]
```

then in your JS should define your columns ....

```
$('#divId').DataTable({
  columns : [
      {data: "DATE"},
      {data: "TYPE"},
      {data: "NAME"}
  ],
    data: response
});
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/4/